# how to get current flat list item data in reactnative using react-native-swipe-list-view

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm not getting how to get the current item object of a flat list

I used `react-native-swipeout` and `react-native-swipe-list-view` and in both examples I stuck.

And on google I found very big answers. Which are not pointing only the particular issue which confused me a lot.

the below is the deleted function when I used `react-native-swipeout` plugin

```
const swipeSettings = {
left: [
    {
      text: 'Delete',
      onPress: () => {
        console.log('-----delete-----');
      },
      type: 'delete',
    },
}
```

All I need is to get the current item object data like below inside `onpress()` when i tapped the `delete` button .

```
{
id: 1,
prodName : "abcdefg",
}
```

That's all, I came from native script background and in that framework I never faced such issue. Because the documentation was crystal clear. But here In react native everything seems to be complicated for me.
Kindly any one help me.

```
<FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => (
            <Swipeout {...swipeSettings}>
              <View style={styles.listView}>
                <Text style={styles.listViewText}>{item.prodName}</Text>
              </View>
            </Swipeout>
          )}
        />
```

entire page

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native-animatable';
import {
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {StyleSheet, Pressable, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import Swipeout from 'react-native-swipeout';
import ButtonPressable from '../../components/ButtonPressable';
var sqlite_wrapper = require('./sqliteWrapper');

const DATA = [
  {
    prodName: 'Added data will look like this',
  },
];

const swipeSettings = {
  style: {
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  autoClose: false,
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  close: false,
  disabled: false,
  onClose: (sectionID, rowId, direction) => {
    console.log('---onclose--');
  },
  onOpen: (sectionID, rowId, direction) => {
    console.log('---onopen--');
  },
  right: [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
      color: 'white',
      text: 'Edit',
      onPress: () => {
        console.log('-----edit-----');
      },
    },
  ],
  left: [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      color: 'white',
      text: 'Delete',
      onPress: () => {
        console.log('-----delete-----');
        sqlite_wrapper.deleteById
      },
      type: 'delete',
      // component : (<ButtonPressable text="delete" />)
    },
  ],
  // buttonWidth: 100,
};

const AddProductList = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const {navData} = route.params;

  const [prodName, setProdName] = useState('');
  var [data, setData] = useState(DATA);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animatable.View
        animation="bounceIn"
        duration={1000}
        style={styles.inputFieldView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={(value) => setProdName(value)}
          placeholder="Add the Product"
          defaultValue={prodName}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.addView}
          onPress={() => {
            sqlite_wrapper
              .insert({prodName: prodName}, sqlite_wrapper.collection_product)
              .then((result) => {
                console.log('---result---');
                console.log(result);
                if (result.rowsAffected) {
                  fetchAllData();
                }
              });

            function fetchAllData() {
              sqlite_wrapper
                .readAll(sqlite_wrapper.collection_product)
                .then((resultData) => {
                  console.log('---resultData---');
                  console.log(resultData);
                  setData(resultData);
                  setProdName('');
                });
            }

            // without sql this is how to update the state having a array
            // const updatedArray = [...data];
            // updatedArray.push({prodName: prodName});
            // setData(updatedArray);
            // setProdName('');
          }}>
          <Icon name="plus" size={16} style={styles.add} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animatable.View>
      <Animatable.View
        animation="bounceInLeft"
        duration={1500}
        style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => (
            <Swipeout {...swipeSettings}>
              <View style={styles.listView}>
                <Text style={styles.listViewText}>{item.prodName}</Text>
              </View>
            </Swipeout>
          )}
        />
      </Animatable.View>
    </View>
  );
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  inputFieldView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    margin: 10,
  },
  textInput: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#b2ebf2',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 7,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 7,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  addView: {
    backgroundColor: '#0f4c75',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderTopEndRadius: 7,
    borderBottomEndRadius: 7,
    padding: 9,
  },
  add: {
    padding: 7,
  },
  listView: {
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    margin: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
  listViewText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});

export default AddProductList;
```

Comment: Can you share your code so it will be easier to understand what you are looking for exactly and to help you?

Comment: @D10S I updated the code, Ask me if you still need anything.

Comment: So you have a list of items and you want to get the item's data when it is being pressed? What is "swipeSettings" ? What is "Left"? why "Left" array doesn't have closing ']'? If you share the whole page it will be easier to understand. the phrase of the 'native script background' is irrelevant to the question, makes the question longer and can only reduce the willingness of other to read it.

Comment: @D10S is it ok to copy paste whole page here ? See the project i updated

Answer (score 0):

So if I get you right you have one generic swipe setting that you want to adjust to each element in the list.

Try changing the renderItem of the Flatlist like this and let me know how it worked for you:

```
<FlatList
    data={data}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        let right = [...swipeSettings.right]; <---- ADDED
        let left = [...swipeSettings.left]; <---- ADDED
        right[0].onPress = () => console.log('edit', item.prodName); <---- ADDED
        left[0].onPress = () => console.log('delete', item.prodName); <---- ADDED
        <Swipeout {...swipeSettings} {...{ right, left}} >    <---- CHANGED
            <View style={styles.listView}>
            <Text style={styles.listViewText}>{item.prodName}</Text>
            </View>
        </Swipeout>
    }}
/>
```

So what I have done here is sending the generic swipe settings to each instance of Swipeout but changed their "Left" and "Right" in order to overwrite their "onPress" function and adjust it to the rendered item.

I know it is hard to understand it like this and it's probably not the best explanation but I hope it will help you somehow.

**EDIT**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native-animatable';
import {
     TextInput,
     TouchableOpacity,
     FlatList,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { StyleSheet, Pressable, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import Swipeout from 'react-native-swipeout';
import ButtonPressable from '../../components/ButtonPressable';
var sqlite_wrapper = require('./sqliteWrapper');

const DATA = [
     {
          prodName: 'Added data will look like this',
     },
];


const AddProductList = ({ route, navigation }) => {
     const { navData } = route.params;

     const [prodName, setProdName] = useState('');
     var [data, setData] = useState(DATA);

     const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
          const swipeSettings = {
               style: {
                    marginBottom: 10,
               },
               autoClose: false,
               backgroundColor: 'transparent',
               close: false,
               disabled: false,
               onClose: (sectionID, rowId, direction) => {
                    console.log('---onclose--');
               },
               onOpen: (sectionID, rowId, direction) => {
                    console.log('---onopen--');
               },
               right: [
                    {
                         backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
                         color: 'white',
                         text: 'Edit',
                         onPress: () => console.log('-----edit-----', item.prodName)
                    },
               ],
               left: [
                    {
                         backgroundColor: 'red',
                         color: 'white',
                         text: 'Delete',
                         onPress: () => {
                              console.log('-----delete-----', item.prodName);
                              sqlite_wrapper.deleteById
                         },
                         type: 'delete',
                         // component : (<ButtonPressable text="delete" />)
                    },
               ],
               // buttonWidth: 100,
          };
          return (
               <Swipeout {...swipeSettings}>
                    <View style={styles.listView}>
                         <Text style={styles.listViewText}>{item.prodName}</Text>
                    </View>
               </Swipeout>
          )
     }

     return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
               <Animatable.View
                    animation="bounceIn"
                    duration={1000}
                    style={styles.inputFieldView}>
                    <TextInput
                         style={styles.textInput}
                         onChangeText={(value) => setProdName(value)}
                         placeholder="Add the Product"
                         defaultValue={prodName}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity
                         style={styles.addView}
                         onPress={() => {
                              sqlite_wrapper
                                   .insert({ prodName: prodName }, sqlite_wrapper.collection_product)
                                   .then((result) => {
                                        console.log('---result---');
                                        console.log(result);
                                        if (result.rowsAffected) {
                                             fetchAllData();
                                        }
                                   });

                              function fetchAllData() {
                                   sqlite_wrapper
                                        .readAll(sqlite_wrapper.collection_product)
                                        .then((resultData) => {
                                             console.log('---resultData---');
                                             console.log(resultData);
                                             setData(resultData);
                                             setProdName('');
                                        });
                              }

                              // without sql this is how to update the state having a array
                              // const updatedArray = [...data];
                              // updatedArray.push({prodName: prodName});
                              // setData(updatedArray);
                              // setProdName('');
                         }}>
                         <Icon name="plus" size={16} style={styles.add} color="white" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
               </Animatable.View>
               <Animatable.View
                    animation="bounceInLeft"
                    duration={1500}
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <FlatList
                         data={data}
                         keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                         renderItem={renderItem}
                    />
               </Animatable.View>
          </View>
     );
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
          flex: 1,
     },
     inputFieldView: {
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          alignSelf: 'stretch',
          margin: 10,
     },
     textInput: {
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#b2ebf2',
          borderTopLeftRadius: 7,
          borderBottomLeftRadius: 7,
          fontSize: 16,
     },
     addView: {
          backgroundColor: '#0f4c75',
          alignSelf: 'stretch',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          borderTopEndRadius: 7,
          borderBottomEndRadius: 7,
          padding: 9,
     },
     add: {
          padding: 7,
     },
     listView: {
          padding: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          margin: 0,
          borderRadius: 0,
     },
     listViewText: {
          color: 'white',
     },
});

export default AddProductList;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But i didn't tried it. I'm very new to coding and if you give answer like this I cannot understand. Kindly give answer only for delete with explanation. Your answer was confusing a lot, as of now I'm not properly aware of those syntax `left[0]`.

Comment: It is plain javascript. left[0] means the first (at index 0) item of the array named 'left'.

Comment: @D1OS But this answer looks like some hacking tricks, I thought there will be a direct way of doing this. I just need id to delete the data when I press delete. Is there any easy and official way ? if there is no such thing i'll use your answer only, your answer is working fine .

Comment: I added an edit so maybe this way will seem less hacky. What I did is instead of having generic swipe settings you now have swipe settings object for each rendered item and you can adjust it as you wish inside the "renderItem" function.